# How to track devise errors on rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have installed devise on rails 4, I am able to register a new user
and add a new record on the database but the email is not been sent.

I have on the development.rb

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
```

devise.rb

```
config.mailer_sender = 'calafatidis@gmail.com'
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

Now when I am signing up I am not getting the confirmation email.
Is there a way to check if there was an error on sending email process ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the console log output, see if it sends. Hope this helps

Comment: The console output doesn't have sending information nor error messages.